# merge dictionaries and have one big dictionary within list

Tags: python

```
payload =  [
                {
                    "Beds:": "3"
                },
                {
                    "Baths:": "2.0"
                },
                {
                    "Sqft:": "1,260"
                },

            ]
```

How would I have such list be like:

```
payload = [{'Beds':"3","Baths":"2.0","Sqft":"1,260"}]
```

instead of multiple dictionaries; I want one dictionary within the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
payload_new = [{i: j[i] for j in payload for i in j}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help. Use the `replace` method to remove **":"**

```
payload =  [
                {
                    "Beds:": "3"
                },
                {
                    "Baths:": "2.0"
                },
                {
                    "Sqft:": "1,260"
                },

            ]


newDict = [{k.replace(":", ""): v for j in payload for k,v in j.items()}]
print newDict
```

**Output:**

```
[{'Beds': '3', 'Sqft': '1,260', 'Baths': '2.0'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 has built-in dictionary unfolding, try this

```
payload = {**payload_ for payload_ in payload}
```

Answer (score 0):

To merge dictionaries in a big dictionary, you can write it this way:

```
payload={"Beds": 3 ,
         "Baths": 2.0,
         "Sqft": 1260
        }
```

output:

```
>>>payload["Baths"]
2.0
```

**views**:

- using `[]` was making it a array/list rather than a dictionary.
- using `""` on keys (e.g: "3") was making them strings instead of integers.